# Htaccess redirection including subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need htaccess that will redirect users accessing subdirectories of specific directory (one that contains htaccess) to corresponding subdirectories on another server.

For example:

server_1/dir_with_htaccess/user_subdir_of_choice ---> server_2/user_subdir_of_choice

No subdirectory woudl actually exist on first server, it woudl just contain htaccess.

Comment: This has been answered about 659365936489 times before alone here on SO. There really is no answered that helped you? Why not? What is your specific issue here? Or do you just want others to do your work for you? You should always try to find a solution yourself first. There are examples, there is a very good documentation. Only if you have a specific issue you cannot solve, _then_ is the time to ask here.

Comment: `659365936489` - so many?